# add more columns in join table using spring, hibernate, JPA Annotations

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

Can we add more columns in a join table annotation? Generally i see people ending up with adding two columns as shown in the below example.

```
@JoinTable(name="mapping_table",
               joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="request_id")},
               inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="requester_id")})
```

Is there any way that we can add another column like having another '@JoinColumn'? I mean something like as shown below.

```
@JoinTable(name="mapping_table",
                   joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="request_id")},
                   inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="requester_id")
                                       @JoinColumn(name="requester_id")})
```

or else having another "inverseJoinColumn". I tried finding solution couldn't make it up.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Use the `@javax.persistence.JoinColumns` (note the **'s'** at the end) annotation to define mappings for composite foreign keys. You should have something like the following:</strike>

```
@JoinTable(name="mapping_table",
               joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="request_id")},
               inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumns({
                   @JoinColumn(name="requester_id"),
                   @JoinColumn(name="requester_id")})
               }
)
```

I think it should work.

Sorry for the first answer: I think that the `@JoinColumns` annotation can't be used inside a `@JoinTable` one. So I decided to investigate a little bit more.

I created 2 tables:

1. A `Student` entity class with an embedded id composed by first name and last name.
2. A `Teacher` entity class with an automatic long id and a `Set<Student>` as property.

I mapped the `Set` property with a `@ManyToMany` relationship, and I used an array of `@JoinColumn` annotations in the `inverseJoinColumns` property:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
        name="STUDENT_TEACHER",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="TEACHER_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="STUDENT_FIRSTNAME"),
            @JoinColumn(name="STUDENT_LASTNAME")
        }
)
private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<Student>();
```

I made some tests to check that all was working fine, and I had no problems (the fetch type is just to have easier test cases). I add here the code of the 2 entities I'm using:

Student.java

```
@Entity
public class Student {

    @EmbeddedId
    private Id id = new Id();

    public Id getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Id id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Embeddable
    public static class Id implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
        private String studentFirstname;

        @Column(name="LAST_NAME")
        private String studentLastname;

        public Id() { }

        public Id(String firstname, String lastname) {
            studentFirstname = firstname;
            studentLastname = lastname;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj instanceof Id) {
                Id id = (Id)obj;
                return studentFirstname.equals(id.studentFirstname) &&
                        studentLastname.equals(id.studentLastname);
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return studentFirstname.hashCode() + studentLastname.hashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Teacher.java

```
@Entity
public class Teacher {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String firstname;

    private String lastname;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name="STUDENT_TEACHER",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="TEACHER_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns={
                @JoinColumn(name="STUDENT_FIRSTNAME"),
                @JoinColumn(name="STUDENT_LASTNAME")
            }
    )
    private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<Student>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public Set<Student> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }

    public void addStudents(Student student) {
        students.add(student);
    }
}
```

You just have to adapt the code to your particular situation. I hope you can solve your problem with this answer.

**EDIT:**

I let Hibernate create the tables with the `hbm2ddl.auto` option set to `update`. It created a `STUDENT` table, a `TEACHER` table and a `STUDENT_TEACHER` join table. I add here the `CREATE TABLE` statements generated (using MySQL):

STUDENT table:

```
CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `FIRST_NAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `LAST_NAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`FIRST_NAME`,`LAST_NAME`)
)
```

TEACHER table:

```
CREATE TABLE `teacher` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

STUDENT_TEACHER table:

```
CREATE TABLE `student_teacher` (
  `TEACHER_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `STUDENT_FIRSTNAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `STUDENT_LASTNAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TEACHER_ID`,`STUDENT_FIRSTNAME`,`STUDENT_LASTNAME`),
  KEY `FK13A0C19E102E6B8F` (`STUDENT_FIRSTNAME`,`STUDENT_LASTNAME`),
  KEY `FK13A0C19EC177BFF2` (`TEACHER_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK13A0C19EC177BFF2` FOREIGN KEY (`TEACHER_ID`) REFERENCES `teacher` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK13A0C19E102E6B8F` FOREIGN KEY (`STUDENT_FIRSTNAME`, `STUDENT_LASTNAME`) REFERENCES `student` (`FIRST_NAME`, `LAST_NAME`)
)
```

Comment: Ya i'll try it eternay. thanks for the suggestion :) i'll reply back after trying it.

Comment: @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="mappiing_table", joinColumns = { 
             @JoinColumn(name="t_id", nullable=false) },                         inverseJoinColumns = {
 @JoinColumns({         @JoinColumn(name="p_id",referencedColumnName="id",     nullable=false, updatable=false) ,        @JoinColumn(name="p_l_id",referencedColumnName="l_id", nullable=false, updatable=false) })
    })

Comment: I get the following error 
"Type mismatch: cannot convert from JoinColumns to JoinColumn". I have followed the syntax seeing the doc but still i get this error.

Comment: I modified completely my answer as I realized that my first solution couldn't be used inside a `@JoinTable` annotation.

Comment: May i know how the two columns FIRST_NAME and LAST_NAME gets matched with the STUDENT_FIRSTNAME AND STUDENT_LASTNAME in STUDENT_TEACHER mapping table? i mean there are no referencecolumns specified in order to match those columns defined in Student class. Could u elaborate it please.

Comment: I added the CREATE TABLE statements generated for each table.