# Mapping multiple tables to one List Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I've been searching over the web to find out a solution for this. It seems nobody has the answer... I start thinking i'm in wrong way adressing the problem.

Let's see if i can explain easy.

Im developing a contract maintenance. (table: **contrat_mercan**). For the contract, we will select a category (table: **categoria**), each category has qualities (table: **calidad**) in relation 1 - N (relationship table **categoria_calidad**).

This qualities must have a value for each contract where the category is selected, so I created a table to cover this relationship: **contrato_categoria_calidad.**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "contrato_categoria_calidad") 
public class ContratoCategoriaCalidad implements Serializable{

    // Constants --------------------------------------------------------
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1821053251702048097L;

    // Fields -----------------------------------------------------------
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "CCC_ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "CONTRAT_MERCAN_ID")
    private int contratoId;

    @Column(name = "CATEGORIA_ID")
    private int categoriaId;

    @Column(name = "CALIDAD_ID")
    private int calidadId;

    @Column(name = "VALOR")
    private double valor;

    .... getters/ setters
```

In this table I wanted to avoid having an `Id`, three fields are marked as FK in database and first attempts where with `@JoinColumn` in the three fields. But it does not worked for hibernate.

Anyway, now **ContratoCategoriaCalidad** is behaving okay as independent entity. But I will need to implement all maintenance, updates, deletes for each case manually... :(

What I really want, (and I think is a better practice) is a cascade when I `saveOrUpdate` the contract as the other entities do, but I don't find the way to make a **List** in contrat_mercan table.

This is working perfect for other relationships in same table:

```
@OneToOne 
@JoinColumn(name="CONDICION")
private Condicion condicion;

@OneToMany (cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}) 
@JoinTable(
        name="contrato_mercan_condicion",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="CONTRATO_MERCAN_ID")
        ,inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="CONDICION_ID")
)
private List<Condicion> condiciones;
```

But all my attempts to map this failed, what i want, is to have in my Java entity **contrat_mercan** a field like this:

```
private List<ContratoCategoriaCalidad> relacionContratoCategoriaCalidad;
```

not a real column in database, just representation of the relationship.

I found solutions to join multiple fields of the same table, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383045/add-more-columns-in-join-table-using-spring-hibernate-jpa-annotations), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845842/multi-column-join-in-hibernate-jpa-annotations), but not to make a relationship with 3 tables...

Any idea? Im doing something wrong? Maybe i must use intermediate table **categoria_calidad** to perform this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access a list of related ContratoCategoriaCalidad objects from Contrato entity you need to declare a relationship between those two entities using proper annotations.

In ContratoCategoriaCalidad class change field to:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "CONTRATO_ID")
private Contrato contrato;
```

In Contrato class add field:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "contrato")
private List<ContratoCategoriaCalidad> relacionContratoCategoriaCalidad;
```

If you want to enable cascade updates and removals consider adding cascade = CascadeType.ALL and orphanRemoval = true attributes to @OneToMany annotation.

Hope this helps!